# Extremum of function. Need help!

Tags: calculus

I find that example but how to proof that 0 is the minimum and that derivative change sign on any neighbourhood of point? I see on Desmos that it is work, and derivative is positive and negative, but can anybody help to proof it? I tried to understand how to proof it by the change of derivative sign but it's nightmare for me with my level of math)

$$
f(x)=\cases{x^4\Bigl(2+\sin{1\over x}\Bigr), &$x \ne 0$\cr 0, &$x=0$}
$$
Thank you!

Comment: hint:  $-1\le \sin(1/x)\le 1$ so can you show for $x\neq 0$ then $f(x)>0$.

Comment: @zwim Ок. I can only mention that sin(1/x) is bounded function and for this function always greater than 0? And can I proof the sign only because the function isn't monotonic on any neighbours?

Comment: $x^4>0$ and $2+\sin(1/x)\ge 1$ you don't care about variations, just that it is positive, i.e. greater than $0$ the supposed minimum.

Comment: Thanks! Do you have any answer about second proof that the function is not monotonic on any neighbourhood?

Comment: @Krutya Set $x$ to the three values $$\left(\frac{2}{\pi} - \frac{1}{1000}\right), ~\left(\frac{2}{\pi}\right), ~\left(\frac{2}{\pi} + \frac{1}{1000}\right)$$ and see what happens with a calculator.